# Serial communication in MSP430

Tags: uart, msp430

I am using MSP430G2553. If I write the following code in energia-0101E0014 doesn't gives any error but in serial monitor data doesn't print but LED blinks perfectly. I know COM port settings and Baud Rate settings and they are correct.

```
#define LED RED_LED

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(4800);
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.print("Hello world\n");

    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: What is the board you are using? Is it Launchpad? If so, which revision it is? What J3 jumpers configuration do you have? I remember that I had to switch J3 jumper on Launchpad board (rev 1.5) in HW UART position in order to use USCIA0 module. After that I could use `/dev/ttyACM0` file to access serial console (via `minicom` or just `stty` and `echo`/`cat`).

Comment: I'm assuming that RED_LED is declared elsewhere?  I'm not familiar with Energia

Answer (score 0):

Just change Serial to Serial1 . Then run your code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)